# About morphisms of Artin stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I read the following question .
([Morphism of Artin stacks](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62300/148068))
In Mr.skirvin’s answer,I found the statement “ Given surjective, representable $\phi:\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$, we obtain a surjective map of atlases $X \to Y$.  Therefore $dim_x(X) \geq dim_{\phi(x)}(Y)$ for all points $x$.”

Why is this true?(Is it easy scheme-theoretic discussion?)

Comment: Seems false as stated. If $X = V(xy,xz) \subseteq \mathbf A^3$ is the union of a plane and a line, $Y = \mathbf A^2$ is a plane, and $X \to Y$ contracts the line, then the stated inequality is false for all $x \in X$ on the line that gets contracted. There's probably a result if you take the maximum over all $\dim_x(X)$ for $x \in f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Why is the maximum larger than $dim_{\phi(x)}(Y)$? Are there some conditions for the statement being true?

Comment: Actually an even easier example of this phenomenon is the morphism $U \amalg Z \to X$ for any open $U \subseteq X$ with complementary closed $Z \subseteq X$. In this case the map is a bijection, showing that maximum is still not enough. It's just really wrong if $X$ is allowed to be reducible.

Comment: Thank you for the comment again.These means that the strategy of proving the question (https://mathoverflow.net/q/62300/148068) is wrong?

Comment: And I originally want to know whether the morphism from the moduli stack of filtered sheaves on a projective surfaces to the moduli stack of coherent sheaves on it by defining forgetting filtration is smooth .Is this difficult?